# How do you log out using the keyboard in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-10.04

In ubuntu 10.04 is their a keyboard shortcut to log out? i went to keyboard shortcuts and the set tlog out option is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> but when i do click that it just bring down the shut down/restart/suspend and hibernate option but no log out option, does any one know of a work around?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/69114/how-do-i-logout-using-only-the-keyboard

Comment: i actually have tried that one and it didnt work, maybe since that is for 11.04 and not 10.04. there is already a log out option currently there and it's set to ctrl+alt+delete, its just when i press that there is no log out option